# Grid Search of seed in randomized machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I was wondering if tuning a seed with cross-validation in order to maximize the performance of an algorithm heavily based on a randomness factor is a good idea or not. I have created an Extra Tree Classifier which performs very bad with basically every seed except the one I found by using grid search. I think this is not a problem because I really don't care about how the conditions were set as long as they classify correctly, therefore I should have the ability to try running the algorithm with different seeds until it works, in order to find the best set of casual conditions for each split. Am I right?

Comment: Careful with language like "set of causal conditions"—remember correlation is not causation.

Comment: Extra Trees take the best split out of a set of casual conditions. I edited the post, maybe it is more clear now.